# 'None' appears out of nowhere in my code

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
print("text")
print("text")
name=str(input("text"))
name=name.capitalize()
tutorial=str(input(print(name,"do you know the rules? (YES/NO)",sep=", ")))
tutorial=tutorial.upper()
```

I can't find the error in my code. Everytime I run it a "None" keeps coming out of nowhere. (replaced some parts of the code so it can be read more easily)

```
Name? >>>HAL 9000
Hal 9000, do you know the rules? (YES/NO)
None #This I want to erase
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in this line:

```
tutorial=str(input(print(name,"do you know the rules? (YES/NO)",sep=", ")))
```

You are getting that `None` because you have an unnecessary `print` inside your input. Your `input` is using the return of that `print`, which does not return anything, so by default is None. You are still seeing what is inside `print` because of the obvious functionality of `print` to output what you are sending inside the `print` method.

View this example that replicates your problem:

```
>>> input(print('bob'))
bob
None
''
>>>
```

To fix this problem, remove that print. Also, change the string in your `input` to use string `format`:

```
tutorial=str(input("{} do you know the rules? (YES/NO)".format(name)))
```

Answer (score 0):

`print` doesn't return a value, so it's treated as returning `None`. Which means that you're effectively calling `input(None)` which prints out "None" before prompting you for input.